# Running counter for tickets in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am attempting to have a running counter as the first column to easily see how many tickets are being assigned to an agent. The number emulator works but instead of raising the ticket number for the agent it counts the ticket date. My current code is:

```
Set @row_num = 0;
SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_number
     , s.firstname
     , s.lastname
     , t.number
     , ts.name AS status
     , o.name, t.created
  FROM ost_ticket t
   JOIN ost_ticket_status ts ON t.status_id = ts.id 
   JOIN ost_staff s ON t.staff_id = s.staff_id
   JOIN ost_user u ON t.user_id = u.id
   JOIN ost_organization o ON u.org_id = o.id
   JOIN (SELECT @row_num:= 0) N
 WHERE s.staff_id IN (27,35,43,45)
   AND t.created >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
 ORDER BY s.lastname
```

How best could I change it where it would have 1, 2, 3, for the agent and then reset for a new agent?

Comment: Why you do `Set @row_num = 0;` and `JOIN (SELECT @row_num:= 0) N` You only need one of those

Comment: This is not legal syntax in any version of SQL Server that I know of because 1) you cannot mix variable assignment and data return in a SELECT statement and 2) `:=` is not the syntax for variable assignment in T-SQL.  What is your real query and/or real DBMS?

Comment: When I saw the `:=` i was thinking mysql, after read mustaccio answer was I realize sql server tag.

Comment: Sorry it is mysql. I mis-clicked the tags

Answer (score 0):

You need a diferent variable to keep track of when agent change.

```
SET @row_num := 0;
SET @agent   :='';

SELECT 
       @row_number := IIF(@agent = s.firstname + s.lastname, 
                         @row_number + 1,  1 
                        ) AS row_number,
       @agent := s.firstname + s.lastname AS agent,
       s.firstname, 
       s.lastname, 
       t.number, 
       ts.name AS status, 
       o.name, 
       t.created
FROM ost_ticket t
   JOIN ost_ticket_status ts ON t.status_id = ts.id 
   JOIN ost_staff s ON t.staff_id = s.staff_id
   JOIN ost_user u ON t.user_id = u.id
   JOIN ost_organization o ON u.org_id = o.id
WHERE s.staff_id IN (27,35,43,45)
AND t.created >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
ORDER BY s.lastname
```